# What is a generalized linear model

Tags: generalized-linear-model, intuition

Generalized linear models have become so central to effective statistical data analysis, however, that it is worth the additional effort required to acquire a basic understanding of the subject.

I am a starter in Statistics and I really having trouble understanding the GLMs. I mean how GLMs work and why GLMs are required.

Can anyone shed some light on GLMs?

Comment: What do you know about linear models, or even about statistical inference in general? GLMs aren’t super advanced, but they aren’t basic, either.

Comment: Maybe dups:  https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/27651/how-would-you-explain-generalized-linear-models-to-people-with-no-statistical-ba,  https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/104399/why-do-we-use-glm, https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/94371/reference-request-generalized-linear-models